Finding the root of a $2 \times 2$ matrix
I've come across this question: Find a Matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$.
Someone answered that this can be done using Cayley-Hamilton (I understand that part), but then it goes on with " Thus $(aA+bI)^2 = ...$", and that's where I'm lost. Why can we express the matrix $B$ in this way or why can we assume that $B$ is of that form? I mean, it works but I don't understand why.
By the way, I'm sorry for asking here, but I don't have enough reputation to ask in the comments there. Answers are appreciated!

Maybe because those three vectors are linearly dependent?

What Cayley-Hamilton tells you about this $2\times2$ matrix $A$ is that it satisfies some quadratic equation, which can be written
$$A^2=pA+qI.\tag1\label{eq1}$$
It is then natural to look for some $a,b$ such that
$$(aA+bI)^2=A.\tag2\label{eq2}$$
Indeed, expanding $(aA+bI)^2$ and using \eqref{eq1} to substitute $A^2$, \eqref{eq2} is equivalent to
$$(a^2p+2ab-1)A+(a^2q+b^2)I=0,
$$
for which a sufficient condition is
$$\begin{cases}a^2p+2ab&=1\\b^2&=-a^2q.
\end{cases}$$
If $(p,q)\ne(0,0)$, this system has at least one solution $(a,b)\in\Bbb C^2$: if $r^2=-q$ and
$r\ne-\frac p2$:
$$b=ar,\quad a=\frac1{\sqrt{p+2r}}.$$

Thanks for the answer! I'm sorry but why is it "natural to look for some $a,b$ such that $(aA+bI)^2 = A$"? That's precisely what I don't understand. Everything after that makes sense to me but I just don't see why $B$, with $B^2 = A$, would look like that...

Not all solutions $B$ will look like that, and we are not even sure a priori that at least one will, but it is natural to try because: 1) $A$ and $I$ are the only matrices we have at our disposal, and 2) that quadratic equation makes calculations on them easy.

There are a few possible explanations. You may think it's just a strategy to find a solution (not all of them), and if this doesn't work, you may have to try other methods. However, we do know if $A$ can be diagonalized (over $\mathbb C$), then it has a square root (actually any $n$-th root) which is a polynomial of $A$.
The idea is we can do functional calculus on the Banach algebra generated by $A$. We can also apply Chinese remainder theorem to get a purely algebraic proof:
If $p(x)=\prod_{i=1}^m(x-\lambda_i)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then $\lambda_i$'s are all distinct, therefore by CRT:
$$\mathbb C(1, A)\simeq \mathbb C[x]/(p(x))\simeq\prod_i \mathbb C[x]/(x-\lambda_i)\simeq\mathbb C^m$$
Note that in the algebra $\mathbb C^m$, any element (a $m$-tuple of complex numbers with pointwise addition and multiplication) has an $n$-th root (by taking the roots pointwisely). Therefore any polynomial of $A$ has a $n$-th root that is also a polynomial of $A$. Here $\mathbb C$ can be replaced by any algebraically closed field.
